# Is there a way to make the MVC Html.Actionlink invisible based on a property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi say I have a view containing:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Invoice Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Invoice Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Organisation
        </th>
        <th>
            Region
        </th>
        <th>
            Total Excluding GST
        </th>
        <th>
            Total Including GST
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate, "{0:D}")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organisation.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalExcludingGst)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalIncludingGst)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and each item has a boolean property `Editable`. Is there a way to make the Edit link visible/invisible based on the value of this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `if`:

```
@if (item.Editable) {
    @Html.ActionLink(...)
}
```

Comment: I agree - there is absolutely no need to make this more complicated, even if you went to further lengths to abstract the logic into an editor/display template you are still going to need an IF statement.

Comment: This is a better answer than the question was asked for, for this situation it is better to not render the link, than to render it and make it invisible

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use css. But if you insist in actionlink

```
Html.ActionLink(
"LinkName", 
"Action", 
null,
new { @style = "display:none" });
```

So if you use it with `@if` statement in view, you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
   <a href="#" style="display:none">I am invisible</a>
```